# Unsupported config option for services/volumes during OpenVAS installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openvas

https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/22.4/container/index.html

After running `docker-compose -f $DOWNLOAD_DIR/docker-compose.yml -p greenbone-community-edition pull` I see these errors:

```
Unsupported config option for services: 'notus-data'
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'scap_data_vol'
```

Note that this command return random errors messages, when I run this second time I see:

```
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'data_objects_vol'
Unsupported config option for services: 'scap-data'
```

- Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
- docker-compose version 1.25.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently used docker-compose version doesn't match the following requirements described in the linked documentation:

> docker-compose version 1.29.0 or newer is required